# serializer.data not showing any data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm still getting to know DRF but when I run the command `serializer.data` it returns an empty set. Here is what I'm working with

models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey
from django.utils import timezone

from accounts.models import CustomUser


class IndustriaCategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(IndustriaCategoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=False, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=500, null=True)
    ups = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    hotness = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

serializers.py

```
from django.db.models import fields
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import IndustriaCategoria, Empresa, Post, Comment


class IndustriaCategoria(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IndustriaCategoria
        fielst = ('__all__')


class PostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('__all__')
```

I have a management command which creates some data so I can just start throwing commands. Here is where the problem comes up:

```
>>> from accounts.models import CustomUser
>>> from forum.models import IndustriaCategoria, Post
>>> from forum.serializers import PostSerializer, IndustriaCategoria

>>> u = CustomUser.objects.all().first()
>>> i = IndustriaCategoria.objects.all().first()

>>> post = Post(category=i, author=u, title='hello world', body='this is a test', link='https://helloworld.com')
>>> post.save()
>>> serializer = PostSerializer(post)
>>> serializer.data
{}
```

Any idea why I got an empty set instead of the serialized data with the proportionated data when created the Post object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to inherit from ModelSerializer instead of Serializer

```
class IndustriCategoria(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = IndustriaCategoria
        fielst = ('__all__')
```